# Exclude a word from a sentence using batch

Tags: batch-file

I have the below provided string assigned to a variable and in need to take out the last string ":  var6" (highlighted) using batch codes.

Alert Raised on: April 12, 2016 2:10 PM Job: 2799377 Tree Type : Server  Tree Name : ALL MASTER SERVERS Nodes : fmsnbu700 Job Policy: FMS7-FM7COREBGPB2NDMP Exit Status: 196 (client backup was not attempted because backup window closed) Client: fm7corebgpb2ndmp New State: Done Alert Policy: Client Job Completion StatusOpsCenter Server: FMSOPSCENTER01 Comment**:  var6**

I tried findstr command with /v option, but it's not working.

As i try to find a solution - Can you please help me with this.

-Abhi

Comment: @Klaus: He is talking about a "text file containing a series of commands that are executed by the command interpreter on Microsoft Windows systems", as the description of the `batch-file` tag said...

Comment: i have mentioned in my question - "using batch codes.".

Comment: @AbhinandanAithal Open a command prompt windows, run `set /?` and read the output help. You can read about string substitutions with example `%PATH:~0,-2%` which applied for your task would be `set "variable=%variable:~0,-6%"` to get assigned to `variable` the current value of `variable` without the last 6 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not clear, if with "take out" you mean "delete" or "extract"

To *extract*, just delete from the beginning to (including) "Comment: ":

```
@echo off
set "string=Alert Raised on: April 12, 2016 2:10 PM Job: 2799377 Tree Type : Server Tree Name : ALL MASTER SERVERS Nodes : fmsnbu700 Job Policy: FMS7-FM7COREBGPB2NDMP Exit Status: 196 (client backup was not attempted because backup window closed)Client: fm7corebgpb2ndmp New State: Done Alert Policy: Client Job Completion StatusOpsCenter Server: FMSOPSCENTER01 Comment: var6"
set "var=%string:*Comment: =%"
echo %var%
```

To *delete* it, you can use the above info (replacing "Comment: var6" with "Comment: " is saver than just deleting "var6", as it could occure somewhere else in the string)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "string=Alert Raised on: April 12, 2016 2:10 PM Job: 2799377 Tree Type : Server Tree Name : ALL MASTER SERVERS Nodes : fmsnbu700 Job Policy: FMS7-FM7COREBGPB2NDMP Exit Status: 196 (client backup was not attempted because backup window closed)Client: fm7corebgpb2ndmp New State: Done Alert Policy: Client Job Completion StatusOpsCenter Server: FMSOPSCENTER01 Comment: var6"
set "var=%string:*Comment: =%"
set reststring=!string:Comment: %var%=Comment:!
echo %string%
echo -----------------
echo %var%
echo -----------------
echo %reststring%
```

Comment: Take out meant i wanted to delete the string var6. So second code you had provided worked fine. Thanks @Stephan